# Still banned from asking questions

Tags: discussion

Am still banned from asking questions at History SE. Not sure why. Kindly remove the question ban.

If the question ban is not removed this is the prospective historical question that perhaps another user can ask:

> The current New York Times opinion piece content is suspicious from
>   this users' perspective, specifically, the flippant conveyance of
>   information and terms used appear to be staged, contrived, an inside
>   job of propaganda and controversy; contrary to the characterization of
>   the source of the content actually being from a disgruntled high level
>   member of the current administration, the source could be or approved
>   to be disseminated by the highest level of the administration itself,
>   i.e., use of the Hegelian dialectic.
>
> After not excluding the above possibility performed research on the
>   topic by reviewing so-called "left wing", "right wing" and "Average
>   Jo" media coverage on the topic.
>
> At the close of a CBS News report [Speculation swirls over author of
>   NYT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcJE9TJDAh8) op-ed "I Am Part of the Resistance Inside the Trump
>   Administration" a former presidential speech writer Jonathan Horn
>   mentioned that during the presidency of George Washington, Thomas
>   Jefferson hired a translator whose job was to create a newspaper which
>   published articles critical of the administration.
>
> > News Anchor: So, Jonathan, from a historical perspective, 'cause
> >     clearly you know a lot about presidential writings, are there any
> >     parallels to this from previous presidencies?
> >
> > Jonathan Horn: Well, if you go back to the very beginning of the
> >     country, when George Washington was president of the United States,
> >     Thomas Jefferson was Secretary of State, and he hired, appointed a
> >     translator to the State Department, with the understanding that that
> >     translator would start a newspaper that would be critical of the
> >     administration, full of anaonymous articles attacking the
> >     administration. So we do have a long history. And if you do go looking
> >     you can find parallels for things, though nothing quite like this I
> >     think has ever happened.
>
> (Interestingly,
>   there was a comment at the CBS News report video yesterday by user
>   [Donald J. Trump](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn9lChDyp6qDg_oBwZ3r1vQ/about) "45th President of the United States of America"
>   which has been removed as of today).
>
> Does any primary source historical evidence exist that Thomas Jefferson, while acting in
>   their official capacity in the U.S. Government, hired, appointed or
>   otherwise instructed one or more individuals to start a newspaper, compose and publish
>   content critical of the administration that he was at that time part
>   of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no current moderator-applied suspension on your account.

I suspect that this might have been automatically applied by SE.  You might find the explanation contained in the following article in the Help Centre useful:

[Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

As you will note, article states explicitly that:

> Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.

The ban is automatically applied by the SE system. Moderators cannot intervene on that. However, the post [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) on Meta:SE is probably a good place to start.

---

As for your other question, I think the newspaper in question was the [*National Gazette*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Gazette), which was founded by Philip Freneau at the request of James Madison and Thomas Jefferson.

Some primary source material is cited in this Editorial Note, [The Origins of Freneau’s National Gazette, 25 July 1791](https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Madison/01-14-02-0046), from the US National Archives.

Comment: _"Edit all of your questions"_ What edits do you suggest to all this users existing questions? Or, for all practical purposes, the question ban is indefinite?

Comment: As I said, the band is automatically applied by the SE system, so I can't really offer any useful suggestions. However, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) on Meta:SE is probably a good place to start.

Comment: What is the SE policy relevant to the edge case of a question being asked at a different SE site which _could_ be _migrated_ to the SE site where users have closed the question based on the reason that it is a historical question? Does a question ban include migration of question from one SE site to the SE site where the user is banned from asking questions? See [What is the History of the Betsy Ross Flag?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33465/21216), https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33465/what-is-the-history-of-the-betsy-ross-flag/33466#comment127299_33465

Comment: @guest271314 That is covered in the post on Meta:SE quoted above "_Migrations are not possible if your account is banned from asking questions on the destination site. The question will simply be closed as off topic, but not migrated._"

Answer (score 11):

Perusing the Questions and Answers listed on [your profile](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/28734/guest271314), I see that your vote totals are:

- on 10 Answers a total of -15;
- on 8 Questions a total of -13.

Perhaps you should note that the community has found your contribuiton to be overwhelmingly negative rather than positive, and the SE algorithms recognize and act on this.

My understanding is that the Question ban is lifted, automatically, when a pattern of contributing Answers that are seen by the community as positive has been unambiguously detected.

[Additional description here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170363/how-many-new-answers-are-needed-to-lift-a-question-ban)

Comment: The description  of how to try to get question ban lifted does not mention editing answers or include the term "negative" https://history.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans. How is a question ban related to answers and what edits to the existing questions do you suggest?

Comment: @guest271314: I am not privy to algorithmic details of the question ban process. I have posted this to help you dig out from the question ban. I suggest you reread the comments to your worst received Answers and Questions, keeping in mind the thoughts (a) commentators perhaps know things you don't, (b) commentators have actually volunteered to share that knowledge; and (c) you have perhaps not been receptive to said comments and advice. I will not be responding further to comments on this post.

Comment: @guest271314 What Pieter said. And: *also* look at your *well received* posts. It seems the community might expect more in a fashion like those than "the worst received". Assume that people here have good intentions – most have and behave accordingly – and that they try to help you, by criticising your posts so that you can edit your posts for the better. You now need some well written and well received answers. Good luck.

Comment: @LangLangC Ok. Posted an answer to a question concerning a topic where have performed a fair amount of research. If the answer can be improved, and if you are so inclined to do so, kindly suggest an edit that would help improve the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I found information on [questionbans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and [answer bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

As well as [this page of advice once banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which includes these specific tips:

- **Are deleted posts taken into account too?**
  If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that will continue to count against your account even if the post is deleted! Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.

  Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions if less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question.

  Finally, deleted answers always count towards an automatic answer-ban on new accounts - so make sure that you've posted a few well-received answers to counter those you've removed.

  It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or respond to them. Therefore deleted posts have an effect on the filter, among many other factors.

  Beware that an account might very well have many deleted posts, including auto-deleted old low-score questions, all of which are only visible to moderators.
- **How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?**

  ...

  Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts. As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.

  If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Comment: @guest271314: You are currently Question Banned on History, suspended until Oct. 7 on Politics, and suspended until Jan. 30 on SO itself Has it ever occurred to you that the common factor in all those occurrences is ***your behaviour and attitude***? Try ditching the persecution complex and the giant chip on your shoulder.,